# Help with editing my narrative story.

Tags: editing, narrative

I know that this website isn`t meant for editing, but my story is a little personal and I was hoping to remain anonymous. This is just a rough draft that might be a little hard to read. The goal is to write a narrative essay which answers the prompt of "how a positive connection with an older generation can enrich our lives". I haven`t written alot of narratives before, so I`m concerned about the structure. My story is about dealing with OCD and how the artist Tupac Shakur helped me with this. I know that might not make sense, but Tupac knew quite a lot about the world around him and spoke about issues in the world in his songs.

I remember in the past when I was living under the rule of dictator in my head. OCD, a mental illness is what doctors would call this dictator. They explained that it caused constant anxiety over something that was pointless to worry about in the first place. To me this was the dictator`s propaganda. At one particular point in time I remember him explaining “That I must “I must go to postsecondary to pursue a complicated mathematical career”.

This is when things started to get out of hand. Weekend nights were spent close to my textbook and a can of Dr. Pepper to keep me a wake. Ridiculous rituals became habits like avoiding paint, tuna, soccer headers or anything that could possibly affect my mental acuity, which as OCD put it “Would derail me from my job path”. Any job in the trades field was sin to think about. After months of listening to OCD it left me feeling like a worn out drug addict. My body weak and used up, my mind tired but hungry for another hit of OCD. Another hit for a small dosage of satisfaction, which in the end would kill me.

If Tupac were alive today he would have been 40 years old, but at 25 he had experienced a lot and knew a lot about the world around him.The song, staring through my rearview, explains how simple life really is but how we as humans overcomplicate it. As the song progressed it was at the point when he explains “See when I`m staring at my rear view I see the world behind me. Once you get and understanding of how the game works then the world isn`t no trick no more. The world is just a game to be played. Just gotta put our mind to it and do it. This single quote showed how ridiculous the belief Ocd led me to believe was. The society that we humans designed is a game with simple rules, one of them being you must pay rent. No one cares of how you pay pay rent the most important thing is

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. As you noted, we're not an online workshop, so this is off-topic for us. Stack Exchange is a Q&A site. You might have more luck with Critique Circle. http://www.critiquecircle.com/

Comment: Thank you for the  comment.  I've been waiting for some time for someone to add a reference for peer review / critique.